# Regarding the use of ".style.something" - javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have the following javascript code:

```
function createDiv(id){
      var temp = document.createElement('div');
      temp.setAttribute("id", id); 
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(temp);
    }

createDiv('upper_outer');

function /*ABSTRACTION*/(e)
    {

          /* Part not shown of the function is working correctly */

          var upper = document.getElementById("upper_outer");

          upper.style.display = "block";
          upper.style.position = "absolute";
          upper.style.height = $(document).height() - init_co[0] + "px";
          upper.style.width = s_box.style.width + "px";
          upper.style.left =  init_co[0] + "px";
          upper.style.top = init_co[1] + "px";
}
```

By the dev console I can check that the div has been created in fact with the proper id, but there haven't been any changes as it should be supposed to regarding the style attribute. Any ideas on this one? (please ignore the variables not displayed in this code, they are correctly implemented).

EDIT:

The function is called. Part of the function is actually working.

Comment: You never call or execute the *style* code part.

Comment: ... replace the  /*ABSTRACTION*/ part with a function name, execute the function, and see how that goes

Comment: I have that working correctly, for sure xD /*ABSTRACTION*/ is put there precisely because the name doesn't matter, if there is a problem it should be able to be corrected with the code I provided...

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Are you sure the `upper` variable is not `null`, i.e., are you sure that `.getElementById("upper_outer")` definitely finds the element, and that there is only one element with that id? _"/*ABSTRACTION*/ is put there precisely because the name doesn't matter"_ - Maybe it doesn't matter, but /*ABSTRACTION*/ is a _distraction_ to us. Why not just put a real function name there so that at least it looks like real code that could run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the answer to your issue in regular javascript, I notice that you are using a mixture of jQuery and plain old Javascript. Since you are already using jQuery, you might as well use it. (I know, right?)

Try this:

```
function createDiv(id)
{
    $('<div></div>').attr('id',id).appendTo('body');
}

createDiv('upper_outer');

//I'm assuming this is created in response to some sort of event.
//Perhaps the event isn't being triggered?
//Are you sure all your variables are defined? - init_co and s_box
function /*ABSTRACTION*/(e)
{
    $('#upper_outer').css(
    {
        'display':'block',
        'position':'absolute',
        'height':$(document).height() - init_co[0] + 'px',
        'width':s_box.css('width'),
        'left':init_co[0] + 'px',
        'top':init_co[1] + 'px'
    });
}
```

Please note: There can only be 1 (ONE!!!!) ID per page. IDs are unique. If this div, with this ID, is getting created multiple times, it is possible that you are not changing the style of the div that you think you are. If you meant to create multiple of these divs, use "class" instead. If you did not, perhaps you should consider checking to see if the element exists before creating it?

```
//Inside createDiv()
if($('#'+id).length)) return;
```

Comment: I already tried that, still not working... It runs part of the function but doesn't change #upper_outer

Comment: Perhaps you should try your own code in its entirety in a JSFiddle and paste the link to it in your question. I am getting the feeling that there is something else going on that it interfering.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't call the function that changes the style.

anyway, there is another parameters in the function that not exist.
who is `s_box` or `init_col`?

try this code, but add the paramters first:

```
function createDiv(id) {
      var temp = document.createElement('div');
      temp.setAttribute("id", id); 
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(temp);
}

createDiv('upper_outer');
addStyle();

function addStyle()
{

      var upper = document.getElementById("upper_outer");

      upper.style.display = "block";
      upper.style.position = "absolute";
      upper.style.height = $(document).height() - init_co[0] + "px";
      upper.style.width = s_box.style.width + "px";
      upper.style.left =  init_co[0] + "px";
      upper.style.top = init_co[1] + "px";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSxQJ/)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention I actually did that and part of the function is working. But the style part actually isnt... (sorry!)

Comment: Yes that because you missed parameters like `init_co[o]` and `s_box`